# SELECT INTO inside a function

Tags: sql, postgresql

This function executes without any errors, but table `bucket` is never created. Any ideas as to why?

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE FUNCTION individual(bucket text) RETURNS void 
AS $body$ 
BEGIN
SELECT 
  (
    bill
  ) AS NPI
  into bucket
FROM 
  buckets    
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the function like so, but still `mob_ind` is not created.

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE FUNCTION ind(out bucket text) RETURNS text 
AS $body$ 
BEGIN
SELECT 
*
  into bucket
FROM 
  bucket  ;
END
$body$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select individual('mob_ind')
```

**UPDATE 2**

What I really need is `mybucketname_ind` to have data.

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE FUNCTION ind (bucket text) RETURNS void 
AS $body$ 
DECLARE
   tablename VARCHAR(50);

BEGIN
tablename := concat(bucket, '_ind');
select 
  npi as NPI, 

  into tablename
from 
  buckets;
END
$body$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select individual('mybucketname')
```

Comment: Do you really want to return void here or do you want to return `bucket`/`text`?

Comment: To create a new table based on a select use `create table as select...`. The syntax `select .. into ...` does something different in PL/pgSQL

Comment: Can you provide an example return? Are you expecting a returned temporary table or a new permanent table?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a value into a parameter, you need to declare it as an output parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION individual (
    out bucket text
) RETURNS void 
AS . . .
```

Comment: This didn't work. I have updated my question with the changes I made based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new table with `<bucket>_ind` as the table name:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION individual (bucket text)
RETURNS void
AS $$ 
DECLARE
    tablename text;
BEGIN
    tablename := concat(bucket, '_ind');

    EXECUTE format(
       'CREATE TABLE %I
        AS
        (
            SELECT npi as "NPI" 
            FROM buckets
            -- WHERE name = bucket   -- not sure what the structure of bucket is but you may want to limit this
        );'
       , tablename
    );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8279f7742a248e90711818310ca74abb) is a working example on dbfiddle.